# Git: how do you document development steps before deleting a branch?

Tags: git

As a new-ish Git user, I like to keep merged branches around to serve as a development artifact showing what code and steps solved an issue. Since it seems everyone prefers a clean branch list by deleting branches once that work is finished and committed, what do you use to preserve the development steps for each specific issue?

(I understand that commits remain in the history after branches are deleted. The point is, as long as a branch exists, it's clear which commits it contains. Once a branch is merged back into `master` and deleted, all you're left is a long `master` history. So, when faced with a long history of undifferentiated commits, how do you document your work in order to identify which commits used to be part of a certain branch — which commits implemented what ticket or functionality?)

Comment: Who’s this "everyone"? And just because they’re deleted on a remote doesn’t mean they have to be deleted locally... and the diffs are always there whether or not the branch is deleted. But keeping hundreds or thousands of branches around... that seems overkill for information that’s generally already available.

Comment: If the branch is merged, then the commits are in the history.  Deleting the branch doesn't delete the commits.

Comment: Yes, the deleted branch's commits are in the history — along with the commits from all the other deleted branches. How can I, from the commits alone, determine which batch implemented which functionality or ticket? (Labelled commit messages are one possibility, but are error-prone and I want to see what other documentation solutions people use.)

Comment: You could use `git-notes` to add a message to the merge commit

Comment: But typically if you find yourself wondering when a feature was implemented, you would just use `git-blame` to track down the relevant commits.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as far as I know your Git repository would have to keep alive the feature branches which are merged into the main branch, because they are reachable from the merge commits in that main branch.

That being said, if you really wanted a workflow which maximized the chance of capturing every step taken by a developer, you might not even choose a merge based workflow.  Instead, you might choose a rebase workflow, which would promote having a completely linear main branch.

Consider the following scenario:

```
remote:   A -- B -- C
           \
feature:    D -- E -- F
```

Doing `git rebase remote` from the `feature` branch would result in the following:

```
remote:   A -- B -- C
                     \
feature:              D' -- E' -- F'
```

Now, doing `git push origin feature` would yield a completely linear update of the remote branch:

```
remote:   A -- B -- C -- D' -- E' -- F'
```

With a linear history, it is easy to read what happened in a branch.  But, using `git rebase` is more complicated than `git merge`, which is something to keep in mind.

Comment: The result is a linear history with less information than keeping branches around forever. What technique do you use to relate commits to units of work? (I know you can expect devs to prefix every single commit with a related ticket number, but that's error-prone. Do you use another method?)

Comment: Personally, I preface every commit message with the appropriate Jira ticket number (we use Jira).  Then, someone searching the history using `git log` can easily see what was done and why.

Answer (score 0):

All commits to any branch are saved in your git repository as hidden branches, regardless of whether you have deleted the branch or not. 
If you would like to access a branch that you have merged into master - for example - after you have deleted it, you could:

1. Look into your git log by typing `git log`
2. Copy the most recent commit id of the branch you merged with the master (some long hash)
3. Check out the branch of that commit by typing `git checkout <commit id>`

Hope this helps!